# Read messages from Telegram via URL

Tags: http, telegram

How can I receive messages from Telegram from URL ?

I can send message, if I make request on url:

```
 https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage?chat_id=%s&text=%s
```

I just need to enter "bot api token", "chat ID" and "text". I need something similar but I need to read messages in chat.

Comment: Use `getUpdates`

Comment: I will receive only:      {"ok":true,"result":[]}    But group contains messages.